# Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \INPUT

Tags: errors, algorithms, input, algorithmic, undefined

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
    \caption{Dolphinn: Preprocessing (data structure)}
    \label{DolphinnPrep}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \INPUT{Metric $(\MM, d_{\MM})$, radius $r>0$, approximation factor $c>1$, LSH family $F=F(c,r)$, data set $P \subset \MM$, parameter $d'$.}
    \STATE Initialize empty hashtable $T$.
    \FOR{$i = 1$ to $d'$}
        \STATE Sample $h_i \in F$ u.a.r.
        \FOR{each $x \in h_i(P)$}
            \STATE{Flip a fair coin and assign the result to $f_i(x)$.}
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \STATE{For all $p \in P$, $f(p)=(f_1(h_1(p)), \ldots, f_{d'}(h_{d'}(p)))$.}
    \STATE{For all $p \in P$, add $p$ to the bucket of $T$ with key $f(p)$.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
./sample.tex:11: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \INPUT 

l.11     \INPUT
               {Metric $(\MM, d_{\MM})$, radius $r>0$, approximation factor ...

?
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The documentation of algorithmic doesn't mention \INPUT. Why do you believe that it should work?

Comment: I was given that code from an overleaf document of another student and he said it works fine @UlrikeFischer, damn! :/ Are you aware of any workaround? I mean by discarding that \INPUT!

Comment: look in the document where it works, and copy the definition of `\INPUT` from there, otherwise hard to guess. defining `\INPUT` to _anything_ would make the error go away, but wouldn't necessarily do what it does in the other document.

Comment: Yes @DavidCarlisle, this is what I tried to do, but there no other mention of `\INPUT`, I wonder if I am missing something with that overleaf, never tried it...

Comment: put `\show\INPUT` in the document where it works and TeX will stop and show its definition

Comment: When I try out your example in overleaf I get the same error.

Comment: I did so before and after the beginning of the document and got a compile error in overleaf. Hmm @UlrikeFischer thank you, that means that something is included there (the document is for a conference) that defines that INPUT!

Comment: `\show` is essentially a forced error, but the error message shows the definition of the specified command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe want `\INPUTS`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcommand{\MM}{MM}% ???

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Dolphinn: Preprocessing (data structure)}
\label{DolphinnPrep}

\begin{algorithmic}
\INPUTS
  \STATE Metric $(\MM, d_{\MM})$, radius $r>0$, approximation factor $c>1$,
         LSH family $F=F(c,r)$, data set $P \subset \MM$, parameter $d'$.
\ENDINPUTS
\STATE Initialize empty hashtable $T$.
\FOR{$i = 1$ to $d'$}
  \STATE Sample $h_i \in F$ u.a.r.
  \FOR{each $x \in h_i(P)$}
    \STATE Flip a fair coin and assign the result to $f_i(x)$.
  \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\STATE For all $p \in P$, $f(p)=(f_1(h_1(p)), \ldots, f_{d'}(h_{d'}(p)))$.
\STATE For all $p \in P$, add $p$ to the bucket of $T$ with key $f(p)$.
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg, I will accept your answer as a generic solution. But for my case, the student had forgotten to show me this: `\newcommand{\INPUT}{\item[\algorithmicinput]}`.

Comment: @gsamaras It should be `\algorithmicinputs` anyway.